# Google Analytics Advertising Features Raw Data that can use in BigQuery 'Raw' Data

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

**1. I want to know about GA Advertising Features Raw Data that can use in BigQuery 'Raw' Data.**

In https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2700409?hl=en,

`you enable Google Analytics to collect data about your traffic via Google advertising cookies and identifiers, in addition to data collected through a standard Google Analytics implementation.`

2. In https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en,
   there are hits.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfp and hits.publisher.dfp. **Do they relate about GA Advertising Features?**

Comment: Hi, could you clarify more your questions? From my understanding, the hits.publisher.dfp and hits.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfp reefer to fields corresponding to the collected GA data. In order to import the GA data to BQ, the schema specified in [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) must be used. You can also find [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089) a sample dataset of GA in BQ.

Comment: @JuanFernándezAfonso Hi, Thank you. I wonder about how GA collects "hits.publisher.dfp" and "hits.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfp". I thought I have to use "GA Advertising Features" to get data about "hits.publisher.dfp".

Comment: @mars.cookie, I am not really sure which information you are seeking for, can you elaborate more on that? Also, if you refer how to access the columns hits.publisher.dfp or hits.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfp you can access it through the ga_session_YYYYMMDD table ,[here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738?hl=en) you can find more information about it.